# Windows cmd.exe detaches from processes after creating them

Tags: windows, cmd, intel-pin, dr-memory

I'm trying to run some dynamic analysis routines on Windows programs, using things like Intel Pin and DynamoRIO. I am running Windows 11. A problem I am having is when I use `cmd.exe` to launch an interactive application, control returns immediately to the interpreter after the application has been launched. This means those apps don't get analyzed properly.

For example, if I use DynamoRIO to instrument the File Explorer like this:

```
drrun.exe -t drcachesim -- explorer.exe
```

Then DynamoRIO returns immediately after `explorer.exe` is launched, and it doesn't actually instrument File Explorer when the user can interact with it.

I've had similar issues with Intel Pin. It seems the root issue is `cmd.exe` detaches from processes immediately after launching them. I am a complete novice Windows developer, so there is probably some mechanism I am unaware of that is causing this. I would be grateful or any insight or feedback here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to note here.

1. cmd.exe waits for console programs but not GUI programs. Use the `start` command to wait on GUI programs: `start /wait notepad.exe`.
2. Explorer.exe will often communicate with an existing instance of itself and then just exit. [Exit Explorer](https://www.askvg.com/hidden-secret-exit-explorer-option-in-windows-10-start-menu-and-taskbar/) and then use Task manager to kill all Explorer.exe instances and then run your command.